# PHP- Group files in a directory to form a playlist

Tags: php, file

I'm trying to group several files in a folder into a playlist using PHP. So, i'm using this piece of code to find and group video files which have different formats into a single name, but its not working.

```
$path = realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . "/vidd";
    echo $path;
    $dir_handle = @opendir($path);
    while (FALSE != ($file2 = readdir($dir_handle))) {
        if ($file2 != '.' && $file2 != '..') {
            if (strstr($file2, ".mp4") || strstr($file2, ".webm") || strstr($file2, ".flv") || strstr($file2, ".3gp")) {

                $fileNamepart = explode(".", $file2);
                while (FALSE != ($file3 = readdir($dir_handle))) {
                    if ($file3 != '.' && $file3 != '..') {
                        if (strstr($file3, ".mp4") || strstr($file3, ".webm") || strstr($file3, ".flv") || strstr($file3, ".3gp")) {

                            $fileNamepart1 = explode(".", $file3);
                            if (stristr($fileNamepart[0], $fileNamepart1[0])) {
                                echo $file3;
                            }


                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And in the Vidd directory there are these files present.

▶ Crysis 3 - CryEngine3 Tech Trailer - YouTube [480p].flv

▶ Crysis 3 - CryEngine3 Tech Trailer - YouTube [240p].flv

▶ Crysis 3 - CryEngine3 Tech Trailer - YouTube [144p].3gp

▶ Crysis 3 - CryEngine3 Tech Trailer - YouTube [720p].mp4

▶ Crysis 3 - CryEngine3 Tech Trailer - YouTube [360p].webm

▶ Crysis 3 - CryEngine3 Tech Trailer - YouTube [360p].flv

▶ Crysis 3 - CryEngine3 Tech Trailer - YouTube [720p].webm

▶ Crysis 3 - CryEngine3 Tech Trailer - YouTube [360p].mp4

▶ Crysis 3 - CryEngine3 Tech Trailer - YouTube [240p].3gp

▶ Crysis 3 - CryEngine3 Tech Trailer - YouTube [480p].webm

my_video.mp4

turisas_interview.flv

my_video.mp4

How can i group these files into a playlist, which will display only the name of the file and not the specific format. So from the above list of files, the program should generate this:

▶ Crysis 3 - CryEngine3 Tech Trailer

my_video.mp4

turisas_interview.flv

my_video.mp4.

I would then make a `ul` list out of it. And then feed the original file to `Video.js` for viewing on browser. 
Can anyone please help me out with this, i'm trying hard, but can't find an easy way to do this.

Comment: Do you want to trim out the file extension & "group by" file name ?

Comment: yes, that could work too. But how to "group by" file name. Doing an explode on "-" or "_" or " " and then performing a strstr on the file names doesn't helps much. Is there an efficient way to do this ?

Comment: Somebody is using Flash Video Download! ;)

Comment: @Maxx the issue is, no code can identify `Crysis 3 - CryEngine3 Tech Trailer` from your file names, without adding your own logic. Try it out yourself.

Comment: Yes i realized it long before i posted the question here :-). But in general how can i proceed if i just want to group file names which has same names before a "-" (a hyphen). I have tried exploding the file name with "-" as a delimiter, then looking for files with similar first name, in the folder. But it just doesn't works. Can you atleast direct me in the right path. I can't seem to get nowhere with this.